# Display value based on two select elements using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using AlpineJS I need to calculate and display a price based on the values of 2 `select` HTML elements:

```
<div x-data="pricing('X')">

  <span x-text="pricing.calculate"></span>

  <select x-on:change="data.level = $event.target.value">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
  </select>

  <select x-on:change="data.count = $event.target.value">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

And I have the function:

```
export default function pricing(plan) {

  return {

    data: { plan: plan, level: "", count: "" },

    calculate() {

      if (this.data.plan == "X") {

        if (this.data.level == "B" && this.data.count == 4) 
          return 100;
        else 
          return 40;

      } 

      return 20;

    }

  }

}
```

The value inside the `span` element is not displayed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by the `pricing` function would already be the "context" of any directives, so you shouldn't reference it with `pricing.` in the `x-text`. Instead, reference the `calculate()` member without any prefix:

```js
function pricing(plan) {

  return {

    data: { plan: plan, level: "", count: "" },
 
    calculate() {
      if (this.data.plan == "X") {
        if (this.data.level == "B" && this.data.count == 4) 
          return 100;
        else 
          return 40;
      }

      return 20;
    }
  }

}

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('pricing', pricing);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.12.3/cdn.min.js" integrity="sha512-XpPnaYn/Y/hcDzJa//4tOusxoA8/blkeeehF/qLAQPm3rej3Ds3msq1lLZCsFtnvnTtpIDQcyua4ZnELbwyy1Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>

<div x-data="pricing('X')">

  <span x-text="calculate"></span>

  <select x-on:change="data.level = $event.target.value">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
  </select>

  <select x-on:change="data.count = $event.target.value">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>

</div>
```